# What does "treacherous weather" mean?

Tags: meaning

In Dune (2021), Narrator speaks about planet Arrakis:

> Narrator: Extreme temperatures and **treacherous weather** events make life outside the cities
> of Arrakis truly hostile, with sandstorms powerful enough to cut through metal.

What does "treacherous weather" mean? I heard "extreme weather" but what does
"treacherous weather" mean?

Comment: Treacherous weather **events**. If weather is treacherous you can't trust it.

Comment: ...because it may turn very bad without warning.

Comment: from dictionary: **treacherous** (of ground, water, conditions, etc.) presenting hidden or unpredictable dangers.

Comment: Extreme weather conditions that could turn dangerous at any time. Also extreme care should be taken or you could put yourself in danger at any time. For instance, black ice on roads could be described as treacherous road conditions. The conditions might not suddenly change but an unforseen event, combined with the conditions, could spell danger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/treacherous), the word treacherous has the following meaning:

(of ground, water, conditions, etc.) presenting hidden or unpredictable dangers.

Extreme weather is something that is predicted, whereas a treacherous weather event is unpredictable, full of surprises.